# Fixed div and fluid height div under

Tags: html, css

I have a fixed header height and a subheader, I want the subheader to fill the whole page, however when I do that, there’s always a slight offset causing a scrollbar to appear as soon as you resize the window in height:

```css
header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 55px;
  z-index: 10;
  background: #263238;
}
.sub-header {
  background: #37474F;
  height: 95vh
}
```

```html
<header></header>
<div class="sub-header"></div>
```

I’ve googled and googled and can’t find an answer.

Answer (score 3):

The two height settings do not equate to 100%. `95vh` leaves `5vh`, however the header is set to `55px`, as such, instead of `95vh` for the sub header, do `calc(100vh - 55px)`.

You will also need to ensure the `body` does not have a margin set.

```css
body{
    margin:0;
}
header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 55px;
    z-index: 10;
    background: #263238;
}

.sub-header {
    background: #37474F;
    height: calc(100vh - 55px)
}
```

```html
<header></header>
<div class="sub-header"></div>
```

Comment: Hooray! That solved everything! :) I'll keep that in mind, didn't know CSS could calculate stuff!

Comment: Off topic : @SW4 can you please help me with this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31071477/collapsible-divs-with-single-slider.ty